# List comprehension using `x,y` vs. printing the results

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I was wondering why I’m getting the following output:

```py
for x,y in zip([2,5],[4,3]):
    print(x)
    print('hello')
    print(y)
```

Output:

```
2
hello
4
5
hello
3
```

While I expected the output to be:

```
2
hello
5
4
hello
3
```

since I’m running on `x,y`, but for some reason, it prints out all `x`’s and then all `y`’s. Any explanation?

Comment: Do you know what `zip` does?

Comment: You'll get your expected output if you just omit `zip`, so what is it that you think `zip` does?

Answer (score 1):

`zip` runs through the input items in order, meaning `zip(x, y, ...)` will access the items:

```
x[0], y[0], ...
x[1], y[1], ...
x[2], y[2], ...
x[3], y[3], ...
...
```

It will continue in that pattern until the shortest input is completed.

In your example, `x = [2, 5]` and `y = [4, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

The zip() function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together.

So in your example, you initially run on: 2, 4. and on the second iteration on 3 and 5

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is consistent with the way that `zip` works - think "zip" as in "zipper."  To get the sequence you want you would be better served by `iterools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

for x in chain([2,5],[4,3]):
    print(x)
    print('hello')
```

```
2
hello
5
hello
4
hello
3
hello
```